# Electron - Executing a program on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, electron

I am new to Electron and i want to build a small app for myself where i can execute programs/games etc on `a href` click.

If i open the electron app it automatically starts the program/game.

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "D:\\Games\\GAMEFOLDER\\GAMENAME.exe";
child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
if(err){
console.error(err);
return;
 }
console.log(data.toString());
});
```

**How do i code it so that it only starts the exe when i click a link?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In renderer NodeJS modules are not accessible. You can use electron main process and renderer communication.

Alternatively you can have a preload.js where you can define you logic and call those methods from renderer. For example refer https://github.com/itsprav/elctron-use-child-process which I have created including your example.

[image]

Comment: @A Praveen Kumar I cloned the repository but I can't find a button to test the execution of a file.

Comment: Once you do `npm install` and `npm start` you should see a Electron app opening with a button "Invoke Child Process". On click of it it would invoke child_process

Comment: @A Praveen Kumar Yes I see now the button :) I changed the path but the button didn't work .

Comment: My baad man it's working :D . In my game path I used \ instead of \\. Thank you so so so much ! I struggled a lot with this.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it solves what you needed?

Comment: @A Praveen Kumar For sure. Just one more thing. What if I want to add more executables ? What should I do exactly ?

Comment: You can make executablePath as function variable and call opengame method multiple times.

Comment: @A Praveen Kumar As a newbie I will be very thankful if you included an example in your post, it will mean a lot to me.

Comment: Done, updated the repo, you can see that in latest pull.

Answer (score 0):

On the renderer page/ process, make the button or href link. Add an event listener to it.

As soon as it gets clicked, send a message to the electron main process via IPC communication.

In the main process , as soon as this message is received, start the exe. So, Move your executable running code inside this message receiving handler/ function.

Comment: I think button would be better because href is used for external website link.

Comment: I'm kinda newbie but I understood what you meant. In my case I'm very limited of what I can actually do in Electron so I doubt I can perfectly execute it.

Comment: Once you are familiar with electron , you will be able to execute your ideas. Also I can see that @A Praveen has answered with code, that's great. You should be able to do now. I will also upvote the other answer.

Comment: Yep. No problem.